# Jcycle END callback with call

Tags: jquery, callback, jcycle

Hi guys I just wanna know if it's possible to refresh my cycle elements at the end of the cycle to go get data from a php page without refreshing the page...

I try this but it's not working at all...

```
$('#thicker').load('thicker.php', function() {
  $('#thicker').cycle({ 
    fx:    'fade', 
    speed: 'slow',
    timeout: 6000,
    end: function() {  
        alert("End")
        $('#thicker').fadeOut("slow").load('thicker.php').fadeIn("slow");
    } 
});
```

it load my data from my php page the first time but at the end of the cycle when all my elements have cycle it dosent go get the new data from the php and it dosent even do the alert...

Is there anyone have a solution? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the cycle plugin is to loop forever so your `end` callback will never get called. You want to specify `autostop: true` or `nowrap: true`. From the [fine manual](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html):

```
autostop: 0,     // true to end slideshow after X transitions (where X == slide count) 
// ...
end:      null,  // callback invoked when the slideshow terminates (use with autostop or nowrap options): function(options) 
// ...
nowrap:   0,     // true to prevent slideshow from wrapping
```

So try adding `autostop:true` or `nowrap:true` to your `.cycle()` options, that should get your `end` callback called.

Comment: Great thanks! Now it works... At the end i can call a function that it's load my data and start the cycle again... 

BUT... why at the end if I call a function that is suppose to fadeOut my div that contain my cycle it just cut the fadeout effect without fade but if I inspect my element I see that my function apply the fadeout on my div with the style attribute in chrome but i dont see it in the web page...

Comment: @Martin: The `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` functions work using timers for the animation and the `.load` is asynchronous. So, you have three things running at the same time and you're probably seeing timing issues. If you want them to run synchronously, you'll have to use the "finished" callbacks to start the next task.